# Decrypting Lua Files from game

Tags: ida, c++, decryption, game-hacking, lua

I'm truing to decrypt LUA scrpits from cocos2dx game (for wiki).

Links to files of game:
[libhellolua.so](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5kmq/31LAqkdpU) (cocos2dx external library)
[example encrypted LUA-scripts](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2z1Z/2ajcLhJ8N) (*.abc files)

I was reading a library in IDA Pro.
This library don't have mention "xxtea".

And i found function getEncyptedFileData:
[pastebin getEncyptedFileData](https://pastebin.com/p9Xupzj7)

This function is not in the original source code of Cocos2d-x.
I think this function is related to decryption (since this function is called nearby with the variable "*.abc").
I can not understand the some lines in this function:

1: I think that this function CCFileUtils:getFileData.

```
v5 = (_BYTE *)(*(int (__fastcall **)(cocos2d::CCFileUtils *, const char *, const char *, unsigned int *))(*(_DWORD *)this + 16))(this, a2, "rb", &v26);
```

2: This loop not readeable. The result of the first line is used in this loop.

```
do
  {
    v6[(signed int)v17 * (signed __int64)v11 % (unsigned __int64)v14] = *(_BYTE *)(v13 + v16) ^ v15[v17];
    ++v17;
    v16 = (v16 + 1) % v10;
  }
  while ( v17 < v14 );
```

3: function getEncyptedFileData return result of this line:

```
v19 = (*(int (__cdecl **)(cocos2d::CCFileUtils *, _BYTE *))(*(_DWORD *)v21 + 24))(v21, v6);
```

Comment: https://bbs.pediy.com/thread-188534-1.htm#1293990
password to unzip: `cocos2d: ERROR: Invalid filename <filename without path and extension>`, ex: `cocos2d: ERROR: Invalid filename DailyLoginReward`

Comment: Are those links valid now? I can't download those and can't understand russian!

Comment: @Biswapriyo, yes. Links valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
  v5 = (_BYTE *)(*(int (__fastcall **)(cocos2d::CCFileUtils *, const char *, const char *, unsigned int *))(*(_DWORD *)this + 16))(
                  this,
                  a2,
                  "rb",
                  &v26);
```

This is a signature xxtea encryption with the sign `rb`. Now you need to find the xxtea encryption key in `this` method. You can either dig a little bit more from `CCFileUtils` or `AppDelegate`(As this article: https://boards.libre.io/threads/decrypt-xxtea-block-cipher-in-lua-file-from-cocos2d-lua-games.297552/)

Another way (my favorite way), is to use frida and hook to the method, print out `this` (arg[0]) using this guide: https://boards.libre.io/threads/decrypting-lua-files.238916/